# jQuery Checkbox event handling with .live()

Tags: html, checkbox, jquery

Newbie to jQuery here. I have a check box that is dynamically added through the following code in jQuery:

```
.html("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' value='7.5'>");
```

I want to be able to eventually call a function if a checkbox is clicked. I have tried using these two variants of code:
for the class checkbox:

```
$(".checkbox").live('click', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

or to call all checkboxes:

```
$(":checkbox").live('click', function() {

    alert('test');
});
```

This isn't working at all. Any ideas?
Much appreciated!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Be sure to check the docs before asking http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.live()` is deprecated. Use the event delegation syntax:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
    alert(e);
});
```

Replace `document` with the selector of the closest parent element that's present when you bind the event handler. I'd also suggest not to use `:checkbox`, as it's a non-native selector and will be slower than `input[type="checkbox"]`

Comment: Good answer, same as what I was going to answer :)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning, that in addition to specifying the input type on the selector "input[type='checkbox'], you can in addition add a class name to further narrow-down the target elements:

input[type='checkbox'].checkbox